# Have a "Page" automatically post on user's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a client that is interested in having the ability for users to opt in on his website to allow his "page" on facebook to post blog posts on the user's walls.  The blog system is completely built from scratch, and I was wondering if this is even possible with the facebook API.  It's not a user posting, it's the "page" itself.  This can only be done obviously if the user gives permission to the "page" to do so.  Is this possible?  If so what part of the API do I need to investigate into.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot post to a User's wall from a page. You can try it out yourself using the [Facebook Explorer Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), by using your Page's Access Token and posting to `/{your_profile_id}/feed`.

You will get an error that says: `(#200) The target user has not authorized this action`, but there is no option for the user to authorized this action.